# modify a form so that the page does not refresh on submit

Tags: php, html

I have a simple form whereby an input field is given a value if a certain button is clicked. The problem is it takes to long to reload the page and I would like to submit it without refreshing the page. I have tried adapting certain AJAX,JQuery scripts from different types but they haven't worked, can anyone suggest a some simple code to use. Here is the basic example:

```
<html>
<form method='POST' action='test2.php'>
<input type='text' name='input_a' value='<?php if($_POST['submit_a'])
{
   echo "test1";
} ?>'>

<input type='submit' name='submit_a' value='a'>
<input type='text' name='input_b' value='<?php if($_POST['submit_b'])
{
    echo "test2";
}?>'>

<input type='submit' name='submit_b' value='b'>
</form>
</html>
```

Comment: what was the problem with the ajax scripts exactly?

Comment: I don't think I adapted the code correctly.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I adapted this using vanilla javascript only, if the use case really is this basic. If server side access is needed, this solution will not help, and you're going to have to learn more about how Ajax works.

HTML:

```
<html>
<form>
   <input type='text' name='input_a' id="input_a"/><input type='submit' name='submit_a' value="a" onclick="setInput(this, 'test1'); return false;">
   <input type='text' name='input_b' id="input_b"/><input type='submit' name='submit_b' value="b" onclick="setInput(this, 'test2'); return false;">
</form>
</html>​
```

Javascript:

```
function setInput(button, setValue) {
    var buttonVal = button.value,
        textbox = document.getElementById('input_' + buttonVal);

    textbox.value = setValue;
}​
```

Here is the example working in JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/6jpNf/1/

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of posting using ajax (you'll have to adjust your code for the response). I assume you need to post because the scenario you outline could very easily be done purely with javascript.

```
$(function(){
    $('input[type="submit"]').click(function(){
         var form = $(this).parents('form');
         var postData = form.serialize();
         postData[$(this).attr('name')] = $(this).val(); // the value for the click won't be retrieved with serialize
         $.post(form.attr('action'), postData , function(data) {
             $('body').html(data);
         });
         return false;
    });
};
```

If you can do it without posting, it'd look like this:

```
$(function(){
    $('input[name="submit_a"]').click(function(){
        $('input[name="input_a"]').val('test1');
    });
    $('input[name="submit_b"]').click(function(){
        $('input[name="input_b"]').val('test2');
    });
});
```